# Add/Delete a property of every object inside JSONB column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

TL;DR: I need two `UPDATE` scripts that would turn (1) into (2) and vice-versa (add/delete `color` property from every object in the JSONB column)

(1)

```
id | name | squares

 1 |   s1 | [{"x": 5, "y": 5, "width": 10, "height": 10}, {"x": 0, "y": 0, "width": 20, "height": 20}]
 2 |   s2 | [{"x": 0, "y": 3, "width": 13, "height": 11}, {"x": 2, "y": 3, "width": 20, "height": 20}]
```

(2)

```
id | name | squares

 1 |   s1 | [{"x": 5, "y": 5, "width": 10, "height": 10, "color": "#FFFFFF"}, {"x": 0, "y": 0, "width": 20, "height": 20, "color": "#FFFFFF"}]
 2 |   s2 | [{"x": 0, "y": 3, "width": 13, "height": 11, "color": "#FFFFFF"}, {"x": 2, "y": 3, "width": 20, "height": 20, "color": "#FFFFFF"}]
```

---

### My schema

I have a table called `scene` with `squares` column, which has a type of JSONB. Inside this column I store values like this: `[{"x": 5, "y": 5, "width": 10, "height": 10}, {"x": 0, "y": 0, "width": 20, "height": 20}]`.

### What I want to do

I want to now add `color` to my squares, which implies also adding some default color (like `"#FFFFFF"`) to every square in every `scene` record in the existing production database, so I need a migration.

### The problem

I need to write a migration that would add `"color": "#FFFFFF"` to every square in the production database. With a relational schema that would be as easy as writing `ALTER TABLE square ADD color...` for the forward migration and `ALTER TABLE square DROP COLUMN color...` for the rollback migration, but since `square` is not a separate table, it is an array-like JSONB, I need two `UPDATE` queries for the `scene` table.

Comment: If you had stored your data in a properly designed schema (a table `squares` with a foreign key), that would be a simple `ALTER TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Adding `color`:

```
update scene set squares = (select array_to_json(array_agg(jsonb_insert(v.value, '{color}', '"#FFFFFF"'))) 
        from jsonb_array_elements(squares) v);
select * from scene;
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=52f2b33d94216b0c12f97d4b33b1c234).

(2) Removing `color`:

```
update scene set squares = (select array_to_json(array_agg(v.value - 'color')) 
    from jsonb_array_elements(squares) v);
select * from scene;
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=18b2c8f9917a08dd5e04c56e3116718f).

Comment: It works, thank you! We can also make it a little bit smaller by replacing `array_to_json(array_agg(...))` with `jsonb_agg(...)`